# I want to know the cumulative moving distance of robot from the bag file of the data which moved the robot

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, graph, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am a ROS beginner. I am doing SLAM of turtlebot 2 in the ubuntu 14.04, ros (indigo) personal computer environment.

I would like to make a graph of time and distance traveled.
Should I integrate the speed?
The error seems to accumulate, is it okay?
Thank you if there are other ideas.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312363/i-want-to-know-the-cumulative-moving-distance-of-robot-from-the-bag-file-of-the-data-which-moved-the-robot./) by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will depend on what messages you have available to you in the bag file. If you're only got the relative movement (speed and angular rates) then you will have to integrate the speed as you described. But if you have odometry messages which include the absolute position or TF frames which describe the absolute position then you could use these instead.

You can use the `rosbag info` command [described here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#rosbag_info) to quickly see what topics you have available. Then you could visualise the topics in RVIZ to see how noisy they are to decide which one is best to use.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2019-01-10**:
thank you!
I have / tf message on absolute position.
I will try to calculate from there.